# How to using the fetched data in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently working on an IOS app, I am trying to design a carousel with the fetched json data. This is how I get the targeted json data.

```
class loadDate: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos = [Result]()
    
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=<api_key>&language=en-US&page=1")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            // step 4
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       
                        self.todos = decodedResponse.results
                    }

                    // everything is good, so we can exit
                    return
                }
            }

            
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
    
 }
```

It looks like I can only use the data in a list view, for example,

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = loadDate()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            List(fetch.todos) { item in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.title)
                            .font(.headline)

                        Text(item.poster_path)
    //
                    }
                }

            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Within this list view, I can access all elements like using `fetch.todos[0].title`. However, if outside the list view, `fetch.todos[0].title` would fail, can someone give some advice on how to use the data outside the list view .

Comment: What exactly is it you want to use outside of the list from the fetch.todos? Just any random element or something selected by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a working example. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

But if `todos` is an empty array, `fetch.todos[0].title` will always fail. So whenever you need to access your todos directly you can use something like this

```
Group {
    if fetch.todos.count > 0 {
        Text("Title of first todo \(fetch.todos[0].title)")
    } else {
        Text("Todos are empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class loadDate: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos : Result? = nil // Step 1
    
    // ...
 }

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var fetch = loadDate()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let todos = fetch.todos {
                VStack{
                    Text(todos.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(todos.poster_path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66695683/14287797